# Execute a snowflake stored procedure using a ssis linked server

Tags: ssis

I have created a Snowflake linked server in SQL server SSMS and can Select from a Snowflake table via SSMS or via the Execute SQL task in SSIS package using open query successfully.  But when I change the Execute SQL task to: EXEC LinkedServerName.Database.Schema.StoredProc I get this: Could not execute procedure on remote server.  Is it possible to execute a snowflake stored procedure from an SSIS package? SSIS is Visual Studio 2019 and my server is Windows server 2019